# How to Join and run NOT EXISTS query in mongoose

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a sql query which I need to convert in mongoose aggregate

**SQL:**

```
Select a.participant_id, a.name 
from participant a , settlementAccount b 
Where a.settlementAccount = b.id
and b.account_type = "FundingAgent"
and Not Exists   
(select 1 from settlementAccount c where  b.account_type = "Tracking" and a.id = c.owner_id)
```

I tried to aggregate in mongoose but stuck at the `Not Exists` part of the query.

**Mongoose:**

```
Participant.aggregate([{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'settlementAccount', // collection name in db
    localField: 'settlementAccount',
    foreignField: 'id',
    as: 'settlementOwners'
  }
},
  {
    $match:
      {
        $and:
          [
            {'settlementOwners.account_type': 'FundingAgent'},
            {'settlementOwners.account_type': {$ne: 'Tracking'}},
            {'id': {$ne: 'settlementOwners.owner_id'}}
          ]

      }
  },
  {$project: {_id: '$_id', id: '$id', name: '$name'}}
])
```

I don't know if this is the correct implementation.
Does anyone know how to combine these queries together?